# Changing hard disk configuration without reinstall

Tags: arch-linux, partition, boot-loader

I have been using Arch Linux since 2013 and I love it

The major reason I tried Arch was that it let me install with / on a RAID-0 partition. My laptop has 2 hard drive bays and I had 2 SSDs

There is a huge performance benefit from RAID 0

Now I got myself an m-SATA drive and a HDD caddy. So I have the option of making a RAID0 setup with 4 partitions

Now I want to know how I can migrate my / partition to a new one without rendering the system unbootable...

Is it as simple as copying everything onto a new partition and editing the GRUB menu to boot into the new root partition?

Comment: Are you booting from the same drive as before?

Comment: My new /  partition will be RAID 0 across all 4 drives.
Right now its on 2 drives